# How to transfer linebreaks from a multiline textbox to a sql database and and then enforce them in a gridview label?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to enter text into a multiline textbox that then gets transferred across into a SQL Server database and then retrieved from said database and displayed within a label in a gridview. So far this is my code on the label

```
<asp:Label ID="NationalProjectDescriptionLabel" `CssClass="bodyText" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("NationalProjectDescription").ToString().Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "<br />") %>' />`
```

However it the linebreaks that are entered in the textbox do not appear to be copying across into the database, to begin with.

This is my code for transferring to the database

```
public static String createNewNationalProject(string strTitle, string strDescription)
{
SqlConnection conn = openConnection();//Open Connection

string strSQL = "INSERT INTO NationalProject(NationalProjectTitle, " +
            " NationalProjectDescription) " +
            " VALUES('" + strTitle + "', '" + strDescription + "')";//Insert Into Statement

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn);//Close Connection

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

closeConnection(conn);
return strTitle;//Display Success
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You could add a special character when you insert, then when you get the info from the db, simply splice on that char. Does that make sense?

Comment: I'm really sorry, I'm quite new to this.. still a student. Could you expand slightly? Thanks

Comment: Why do you think that the linebreaks are not being copied to the database?

Comment: Be careful when building SQL from user input.  Read up on [SQL injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/sql-injection).

Comment: I would look at using an ORM, something like dapper.I would do this, keep it simple, I would add something that you can iterate over, using a foreach loop, and that way you can iterate over that object and show them on new lines. Since this is just a school project, simple is best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the way into the database, if I know I want the data back to be displayed on a label so it looks as though there is a carriage return between each row, I store it using replace

```
REPLACE(@YourString, CHAR(10) + CHAR(13), '<br />')
```

Works for me. Or you can do the replace on the way out of the database. Whichever you fancy.

Just an aside, do yourself a favour and pass your data to a stored procedure using command parameters. Code is treated as a text literal, so SQL Injection is not a concern. Why people write SQL code in the front end baffles me.

Comment: And, you have no error catching around your call to create a database connection. If you get an error thrown you'll end up with open connections.

Comment: I know you said you are a student, but if you are doing whatever someone is teaching you, the person who is teaching you has no idea. Your last line - returning the string passed into the procedure - is commented 'Display Success'. How do you know if the insert to the database was successful or not?